# Quotas in Linux, adding new user

Tags: linux, quota

I have an existing quota setup which works fine for 2 users.

Say I want to add a new user, `user3`. Why is using "edquota -u user3" alone insufficient? Do I need to run [quotacheck](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl8_quotacheck.htm) after running `edquota` for the new user?

Comment: cross-posting is generally discouraged.  http://serverfault.com/questions/168768/how-to-add-quota-for-new-user

Comment: I posted there yesterday.Got no replies  -so i thought this place might have someone who can clarify/answer my question. Seems like not most people use quota.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is - yes you need to run quotacheck whenever u add a new user.